# Ping Pong in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm doing a clone of pong in pygame and I have troubles in the moving of my ball. My question are: 1) How to make that my ball move not at the same time when I press buttons; 2) As the ball reaches his upper border, he moves straight. How should I change my code, that ball go by diagonal; 3) How should I change my code, that ball repelled from sticks?

This is my code yet

```py
import pygame, sys

from pygame.locals import  *

pygame.init()

''' game screen'''
size=(600,600)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('ping_pong')

'''colors'''
navy_blue = [0, 0, 128]
white = [255, 255, 255]
orange = [255, 165, 0]
black = [0, 0, 0]

'''variables'''

y_movement1 = 267.5
y_movement2 = 267.5
x_velocity = 300
y_velocity = 300
gy = 25
sp2 = 585
sp1 = 15

'''functions'''
def borders():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, navy_blue, (0, 0, 600, gy) )
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, navy_blue, (0, 600, 600, -gy))

def objects():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, orange, (sp1, y_movement1, 10, 25))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, orange, (sp2, y_movement2, -10, 25))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (x_velocity, y_velocity, 7.5, 7.5))

'''MAIN LOOP'''
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(15)

    event = pygame.event.get()

    borders()
    objects()

    x_velocity += 5
    y_velocity -= 5

    if y_velocity < gy:
        x_velocity += 5
        y_velocity += 5
    if x_velocity == 600:
        x_velocity = 300
        y_velocity = 300
    if x_velocity == 0:
        x_velocity = 300
        y_velocity = 300
    if x_velocity + 7.5 == sp2 and y_velocity < 300:
        x_velocity -= 5
        y_velocity += 5
    if x_velocity + 7.5 ==  sp2 and y_velocity > 300:
        x_velocity -= 5
        y_velocity -= 5
    if x_velocity == sp1 and y_velocity < 300:
        x_velocity += 5
        y_velocity += 5
    if x_velocity == sp1 and y_velocity > 300:
        x_velocity += 5
        y_velocity -= 5


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_w] and  y_movement1 > 25:
        y_movement1 -= 6
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and  y_movement1 < 575 - 25 -6 :
        y_movement1 += 6
    if keys[pygame.K_u] and y_movement2 > 25:
        y_movement2 -= 6
    if keys[pygame.K_j] and y_movement2 < 550 - 25 - 6:
        y_movement2 += 6

    screen.fill(black)

    borders()
    objects()

    for event in event:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pygame.display.flip( )

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: to 1) Do `pygame.display.flip( )` in the main loop, but not in the event loop.

Comment: to 2) the ball moves straight, because it follows the instructions in you program `if y_velocity < gy: y_velocity += 5`

Comment: to 3) Use [`pygame.Rect.collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) or [`pygame.Rect.collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to test if the  stick hits the ball and change the the direction of movement.

Comment: Probably this question to broad. This are 3 questions in 1. *"How should I change my code"* is to general and not a question about a specific issue.

Comment: to 2) there is the second condition but it doesn't work

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, because the 1st condition was fulfilled and `y_velocity` was changed. So the other condition never succeeds.

Comment: why do you use x and y velocity as your position.

Comment: Can u check my answer and if it works for you then accept it otherwise this question will stay open.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the my corrected version of the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

''' game screen'''
size=(600,600)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('ping_pong')

'''colors'''
navy_blue = [0, 0, 128]
white = [255, 255, 255]
orange = [255, 165, 0]
black = [0, 0, 0]

'''variables'''

y_movement1 = 267.5
y_movement2 = 267.5
x_velocity = 300
y_velocity = 300
gy = 25
sp2 = 585
sp1 = 15

'''functions'''
def borders():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, navy_blue, (0, 0, 600, gy) )
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, navy_blue, (0, 600, 600, -gy))

def objects():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, orange, (sp1, y_movement1, 10, 25))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, orange, (sp2, y_movement2, -10, 25))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (x_pos, y_pos, 7.5, 7.5))

'''MAIN LOOP'''
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
x_pos = 300
y_pos = 300
x_velocity = 5
y_velocity = 2
while running:
    clock.tick(15)
    screen.fill(black)
    borders()
    objects()
    pygame.display.flip()
    events = pygame.event.get()
    if x_pos == sp1+10:
        if y_pos > y_movement1:
            if y_pos < y_movement1+25:
                x_velocity *= -1
    if x_pos == sp2-10:
        if y_pos > y_movement2:
            if y_pos < y_movement2+25:
                x_velocity *= -1
    if y_pos < gy or y_pos > 600-gy:
        y_velocity *= -1
    x_pos += x_velocity
    y_pos += y_velocity

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_w] and  y_movement1 > 25:
        y_movement1 -= 6
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and  y_movement1 < 575 - 25 -6 :
        y_movement1 += 6
    if keys[pygame.K_u] and y_movement2 > 25:
        y_movement2 -= 6
    if keys[pygame.K_j] and y_movement2 < 550 - 25 - 6:
        y_movement2 += 6

    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False

pygame.quit()
```

edit:

you used the x and y velocity as a position and that was the problem. You should use them as the x and y value of a vector. I corrected that and now the movement works fine. But due to that change the peddels weren't stopping the ball. I changed the collision-checks and ... done!

PS:
I recommend using random to generate a random initial velocity.

edit2:

this part

```
if keys[pygame.K_w] and  y_movement1 > 25:
    y_movement1 -= 6
if keys[pygame.K_s] and  y_movement1 < 575 - 25 -6 :
    y_movement1 += 6
if keys[pygame.K_u] and y_movement2 > 25:
    y_movement2 -= 6
if keys[pygame.K_j] and y_movement2 < 550 - 25 - 6:
    y_movement2 += 6
```

should be replaced with this

```
if keys[pygame.K_w] and  y_movement1 > gy:
    y_movement1 -= 6
if keys[pygame.K_s] and  y_movement1 < 600-gy-25:
    y_movement1 += 6
if keys[pygame.K_u] and y_movement2 > gy:
    y_movement2 -= 6
if keys[pygame.K_j] and y_movement2 < 600-gy-25:
    y_movement2 += 6
```

Comment: please consider adding an explanation to state what was wrong and what changes you introduced to fix that.

Comment: @Tibebes.M is it better like this

Answer (score 0):

here's an example (py3)

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

# white color
color = (255, 255, 255)
# light shade of the button
color_light = (170, 170, 170)
# dark shade of the button
color_dark = (100, 100, 100)

width = screen.get_width()
height = screen.get_height()

smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Corbel', 35)

text = smallfont.render('quit', True, color)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # if the mouse is clicked on the
            # button the game is terminated
            if width / 2 <= mouse[0] <= width / 2 + 140 and height / 2 <= mouse[1] <= height / 2 + 40:
                pygame.quit()

                # fills the screen with a color
    screen.fill((255, 128, 128))
    # stores the (x,y) coordinates into
    # the variable as a tuple
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    # if mouse is hovered on a button it
    # changes to lighter shade
    if width / 2 <= mouse[0] <= width / 2 + 140 and height / 2 <= mouse[1] <= height / 2 + 40:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color_light, (int(width / 2), int(height / 2), 140, 40))

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color_dark, (int(width / 2), int(height / 2), 140, 40))

    screen.blit(text, (int(width / 2) + 50, int(height / 2)))
    pygame.display.update()
```